# How to export all data in single csv file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

how to combine all result in single cvs file in table form.

```
Get-ADSyncToolsRunstepHistory | Where {$_.RunProfileName -match "Delta Import"} |Select-Object -Index 0, 1|Select-Object @{N='ServerName';E={"$env:COMPUTERNAME"}} ,StartDate, EndDate, ConnectorName, RunProfileName, StepResult
Get-ADSyncToolsRunstepHistory | Where {$_.RunProfileName -match "Delta Synchronization"} |Select-Object -Index 0, 1|Select-Object @{N='ServerName';E={"$env:COMPUTERNAME"}} ,StartDate, EndDate, ConnectorName, RunProfileName, StepResult
Get-ADSyncToolsRunstepHistory | Where {$_.RunProfileName -match "Full Import"} |Select-Object -Index 0, 1|Select-Object @{N='ServerName';E={"$env:COMPUTERNAME"}} ,StartDate, EndDate, ConnectorName, RunProfileName, StepResult
Get-ADSyncToolsRunstepHistory | Where {$_.RunProfileName -match "Full Synchronization"} |Select-Object -Index 0, 1|Select-Object @{N='ServerName';E={"$env:COMPUTERNAME"}} ,StartDate, EndDate, ConnectorName, RunProfileName, StepResult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to export all results into a single CSV, in that case, it could be done this way:

```
$props = @(
    @{
        N='ServerName'
        E={ $env:COMPUTERNAME }
    }
    'StartDate'
    'EndDate'
    'ConnectorName'
    'RunProfileName'
    'StepResult'
)

$profiles = @(
    'Delta Import'
    'Delta Synchronization'
    'Full Import'
    'Full Synchronization'
) -join '|'

Get-ADSyncToolsRunstepHistory | Group-Object RunProfileName |
    Where-Object Name -Match $profiles | ForEach-Object {
        # select the first 2 objects for each group of objects
        # matching the `$profiles`
        $_.Group | Select-Object -First 2
    } | Select-Object $props | Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This uses [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3) and [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3) to filter the first 2 objects of each profile, this way there is a single call to `Get-ADSyncToolsRunstepHistory`.

Comment: Thank you its work perfectly as expected :D

Comment: I need to run this script in three different servers and that data also should get it Single CSV file . how should i do ?

Comment: @hacrks in that case all the logic should go inside the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock except for the call to `| Select-Object $props | Export-Csv ...` which should be outside. If you have issues with this ask a new question and I'll help you. Make a reference to this answer in your new question

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon 
I have posted the question, can you help me on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575997/powershell-getting-error-no-endpoint-listening-at-net-pipe-localhost)