# Powershell getting error "no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

this code should run in different servers remotely and get the output in single csv file.
im getting this error "net.pipe://localhost/ADSyncManagement that could accept the message"

```
        $servers = Get-Content "c:\serverlist\servers.txt"
$Report = foreach ($server in $servers){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{
$prope = @(
    @{
        N='ServerName'
        E={ $env:COMPUTERNAME }
    }
    'StartDate'
    'EndDate'
    'ConnectorName'
    'RunProfileName'
    'StepResult'
)

$profiles = @(
    'Delta Import'
    'Delta Synchronization'
    'Full Import'
    'Full Synchronization'
) -join '|'

Get-ADSyncToolsRunstepHistory | Group-Object RunProfileName |
    Where-Object Name -Match $profiles | ForEach-Object {

        $_.Group | Select-Object -First 2
        
    }
     }} Select-Object $props | Export-Csv c:\serverlist\export.csv -NoTypeInformatione
```

Comment: Take a look at the help files regarding function and variable scopes, when using PSRemoting. Specifically, focus on $using, or -ArgumentList options. Also, one of your variable names does not match.

Comment: @hacrks, What is the purpose of this Script? What is the Environment in which the Script is being executed? Where is the Variable `$props` defined in the script?

Comment: @MadhurajVadde this script is used to pull report from AzureAD Connect sync History, its should run in multiple remote servers, for testing i executed in one test server. '$props' i defined in 4th line as '$prope' (Spelling mistake).

Comment: @hacrks, after correcting the spelling mistake, whats the error you see ?